# Tensorflow unable to reshape a image

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, discord.js

Hi i am unable to use an url to be decoded and classified using tensorflow and mobile net i get the url in discord.js of an image and fetch it with node fetch and then buffer it and then decode it can anyone tell me what resolution does the error mean so i can resize it I have this code

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const mobilenet = require('@tensorflow-models/mobilenet');
const tfnode = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node')
module.exports.run = async(client, message) => {
    message.reply('kk')

   let filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
    const collector = new MessageCollector(message.channel, filter, {max: 1})
    collector.on('end', async m => {
        m.forEach(async(m)=> {    
            m.attachments.forEach(async(u) => {console.log(u.url)            
               let res=  await fetch(u.url)
            const buffer = await res.buffer()
            const tens = tfnode.node.decodeImage(buffer)
            const model = await mobilenet.load();
    const predictions = await model.classify(tens);
    
    console.log('Predictions: ');
    console.log(predictions);
})

})



    })

};


module.exports.help = {
    name: "classify",
    aliases: ["cl"],
    description: "classify images",
    usage: "(command name)",
    category: "Ai-commands",
    cooldown: 0// Counted in MS
};

module.exports.config = {
    restricted: false,
    ownerOnly: false
};
```

and getting this error

```
[UNHANDLED REJECTION] Error: Invalid TF_Status: 3
Message: Input to reshape is a tensor with 200704 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 150528
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jimp to resize it to 720p and feed that to tfjs